# Docker: cant access my local MongoDB container when running my application in a container

Tags: docker

I have run a python application that uses a container MongoDB container as a database.

When running my controller application on local I have no issues to access the Mongo database.

This is my docker file for my application.

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python ./controller.py
```

I run my Mongo database with the next command.

```
sudo docker run -p 27027:27017 -d --name my-local-db --network local_bridge mongodb
```

And my application

```
sudo docker run -p 8000:8000 -d --name scrapper-controller --network local_bridge scrapper-controller
```

I have inspected my local_bridge on docker and I can see that both containers are in the same network.

```
[
    {
        "Name": "local_bridge",
        "Id": "fa2609918a702e51ecba93920434b992abf98249c90955d6ac700b59a5089166",
        "Created": "2019-09-29T00:46:11.301246442+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "bcf382d955e0492991e73a3659e729ea6ddd6b4514809f05bb11e43b92a9ecdb": {
                "Name": "scrapper-controller",
                "EndpointID": "f51340bf27e553b3936ff580ce396896f8d1c14e9d0b81ae3bc869be97106db6",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ceaea1d9f6317cd224c2fe96a0ce6fd6e6740661bba2f0bc014f5b55054eab99": {
                "Name": "my-local-db",
                "EndpointID": "95f3cd136d7810b8e168e0e01e0ab9d4667122f058d59ddd2319ada6888434cc",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Any idea what is failing here?

Comment: How exactly is it failing?

Comment: @DavidMaze get a timeout on the connection with my database, something that happens when I run my scrapper-configuration on a container. Otherwise everything is working